# Ruby: Monkey patch selenium driver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, monkeypatching

##### What I want ?

I want to extract all the capabilities from driver instance, as soon as it is created.

##### Setup

I am creating a fresh driver instance.

```
def create_my_selenium_driver
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  puts '[DRIVER CREATED] '
end
create_my_selenium_driver()
```

##### What have I tried ?

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Driver
  bridge = instance_method(:create_bridge)
  define_method(:create_bridge) do
    driver = bridge.bind(self).call
    $driver = driver
  end
end
```

I was trying the above piece of code but unable not able override the `create_bridge` method. I need to do it both for `chrome` and `remote`.

Note: Those 2 snippets are present in different files.

PS: My use case is to override it and **not to pass the already created driver instance through any method**. I want to intercept any anytime any selenium driver gets created on my system.

Can anyone help me achieve that?
Thanks in advance !!

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Driver
  bridge = instance_method(:create_bridge)
  define_method(:create_bridge) do
    driver = bridge.bind(self).call
    $driver = driver
  end
end
```

As already mentioned, I have tried using the `instance_method`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the capabilities at any time pretty much. In regular selenium (Which you seem to be using), you simply do

```
0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x..f8b84161a7230ca browser=:chrome>

0> driver.capabilities
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:0x00007fc886665f98 @capabilities={:timeouts=>{:implicit=>0, :page_load=>300000, :script=>30000}, :browser_name=>"chrome", :browser_version=>"111.0.5563.146", :platform_name=>"linux", :accept_insecure_certs=>false, :page_load_strategy=>"normal", :set_window_rect=>true, :unhandled_prompt_behavior=>"dismiss and notify", :strict_file_interactability=>false, "chrome"=>{"chromedriverVersion"=>"111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995})", "userDataDir"=>"/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.PtFi9k"}, "goog:chromeOptions"=>{"debuggerAddress"=>"localhost:42993"}, "networkConnectionEnabled"=>false, "webauthn:extension:credBlob"=>true, "webauthn:extension:largeBlob"=>true, "webauthn:extension:minP…
```

Or if you want it at runtime then the `#initialize` method in here is where you wanna look

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Chrome
      class Driver < Chromium::Driver
```